# Send serial value and convert them to float?

Tags: python, serial-port, pygame

I trying to convert a serial data to float.

I send a serial data to other program that need a float value, but i dont know how i do.

The values that i send are between 0 and 180, and these values are received like degrees, but i need that values like degrees.
How i do??

```
while True:
    while z == True:
        x = x+1
        print x
        if x == 180:
            z = False
    while z == False:
        x = x-1
        print x
        if x == 0:
            z = True


    try:
        envio=ser.write("x")      # write a string
        #print envio
    except Exception, e:
        print "Error en \n\t "+str(e)+"\n"
        ser.close
```

And x value are received in this script

```
ser.open()
degree = ser.read() 

for x in range(1,400,10):
    linea = (432,200)     
    linea_len = 100 
    x = linea[0] + math.cos(math.radians(degree)) * linea_len 
    y = linea[1] + math.sin(math.radians(degree)) * linea_len
```

but the x send by serial seems is a binary, and i need a float.

I hope you can help me
thanks you!!

**********************EDIT*************************

Tho complement the question

Complete code to send data

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Aug 14 15:47:07 2014

@author: Zucra
"""

import serial
ser = serial.Serial()  # open first serial port
ser.port = 2
ser.baudrate = 4800
x=0
z = True
try:
    ser.open()
except Exception, e:
    print "Error en \n\t "+str(e)+"\n"
print ser.name          # check which port was really used

#for i in range(1,1000):
while True:
    while z == True:
        x = x+1
        print x
        if x == 9:
            z = False
    while z == False:
        x = x-1
        print x
        if x == 0:
            z = True      
    try:
        envio=ser.write("x")      # write a string
        #print envio
    except Exception, e:
        print "Error en \n\t "+str(e)+"\n"
        ser.close
```

Complete code of code that receive serial

```
import pygame
import sys, serial
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
WIDTH = 865
HEIGHT = 286



ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = 2
ser.baudrate = 4800


def load_image(filename, transparent=False):
        try: image = pygame.image.load(filename)
        except pygame.error, message:
                raise SystemExit, message
        image = image.convert()
        if transparent:
                color = image.get_at((0,0))
                image.set_colorkey(color, RLEACCEL)
        return image



screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Angulo Pygame")
background_image = load_image('fondo.png')
ser.open()
degree = float(ser.read(1)) 
# se define la letra por defecto
fuente = pygame.font.Font(None, 20)

screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0))




while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                sys.exit()


#    for event in pygame.event.get():
#        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
#            sys.exit() 
#        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
#            if event.key == K_LEFT:
#                if degree < 180 : 
#                    degree = degree + 1
#            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
#                if degree > 0:
#                    degree = degree - 1
#            elif event.key == K_ESCAPE:
#                sys.exit()
#                ser.close()              
    for x in range(1,400,10):
        linea = (432,200)     
        linea_len = 100 
        x = linea[0] + math.cos(math.radians(degree)) * linea_len 
        y = linea[1] + math.sin(math.radians(degree)) * linea_len

    # then render the line linea->(x,y)
    screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0))
    texto = "%d" % (degree)
    mensaje = fuente.render(texto, 1, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(mensaje, (450, 185))
    pygame.draw.line(screen, Color("red"), linea, (x,y), 5)
    pygame.display.flip() #vuelca imagen
```

Comment: what are the initial values of `x`, `z` and `ser` in the first part?

Comment: Bcause i dont put all code, only extracts

import serial
ser = serial.Serial()  # open first serial port
ser.port = 2
ser.baudrate = 4800
x=0
z = True

Comment: can you provide a link to the serial? It is really vague what is going on in your code without an input.

Comment: `ser.write("x")` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: How can i send a value of variable by serial??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what you mean by x is binary, but have you tried

```
degree = float(ser.read())
```

Comment: Thanks!

I try that

degree = float(ser.read(1))

but the problem is same, when i use a number like string as "9", the program that receive the serial data, works fine, but if i replace 9  to a variable like X, the program not recognize the value of x, still this value are int.

Whats happen??

Comment: Can you do print(ser.read()). We need to see what you mean by binary.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the data as binary, or you can send it in one of several text representations.

To send it as binary data:

```
import struct

ser.write(struct.pack("!f", x))             # On sending side

degree = struct.unpack("!f", ser.read(4))   # On receiving side
```

The standard text format for serializing Python data is called "pickle":

```
import pickle

pickle.dump(x, ser)                         # On the sending side

degree = pickle.load(ser)                   # On the receiving side
```

Comment: Thanks you!, but how i can to apply that?, pickle seems need a file, and struck still appears the float error. :S